# Problema con KeyListener en juego Pong

Tags: java, java-swing, java-awt

Estoy haciendo un juego pong sencillo, la pelota ya funciona pero los eventos de teclado en las raquetas no funcionan (no tienen movimiento). He intentado hacer algunos ejercicios sencillos en un proyecto aparte y parece que las teclas no son identificadas.

He intentado ya varias cosas y no entiendo porque pase esto, posiblemente el problema esté en actualizar las raquetas.

(StackOverflow me pedía más información ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
//Clase Eventos

public class Eventos extends KeyAdapter {
    boolean w;
    boolean s;
    boolean up;
    boolean down;

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        super.keyPressed(e);
        int tecla = e.getKeyCode();
        if(tecla == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
            down = true;
        }
        if(tecla == KeyEvent.VK_W){
            w = true;
        }
        if(tecla == KeyEvent.VK_S){
            s = true;
        }
        if(tecla == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            up = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        super.keyReleased(e);
        int tecla = e.getKeyCode();
        if(tecla == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
            down = false;
        }
        if(tecla == KeyEvent.VK_W){
            w = false;
        }
        if(tecla == KeyEvent.VK_S){
            s = false;
        }
        if(tecla == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            up = false;
        }
    }
}
//Clase Ventana
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class Ventana extends JPanel {
    int x=0, y=0,angleX=1,angleY=1;
    int x2=0,y2=0,x3=875,y3=510;

    public  Ventana(){
        JFrame marco = new JFrame();
        marco.setVisible(true);
        setBackground(Color.black);
        marco.setSize(900,600);
        addKeyListener(new Eventos());
        marco.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        marco.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        marco.add(this);
    }

    public void move(){
        if(x==0){
            angleX = 1;
        }else if(x+angleX>=getWidth()-50){
            angleX = -1;
        }else if(y==0){
            angleY=1;
        }else if(y+angleY>=getHeight()-50){
            angleY=-1;
        }
        x = x + angleX;
        y = y + angleY;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillOval(x,y,20,20);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(x2,y2,10,40);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(x3,y3,10,50);
    }

    public void moverR(){
        if(Eventos.s==true){
            y2--;
        }
        if (Eventos.w==true){
            y2++;
        }
        if (Eventos.up==true){
            y3++;
        }
        if (Eventos.down==true){
            y3--;
        }
    }
}

//Clase Principal
public class Principal {
    Ventana v;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Ventana v = new Ventana();

        while(true) {
            Thread hilo1 = new Thread();
            v.move();
            v.moverR();
            v.repaint();
            hilo1.sleep(7);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sucede nada porque `marco` no tiene registrados los eventos del teclado sino que los tiene el `JPanel` de clase `Ventana`.

**Ocurre éste detalle:**
Como el contenedor standard del `JFrame` toma el *focus* de la vista de la aplicación entonces deja al `JPanel` de clase `Ventana` detrás sin ninguna interacción con el usuario, por tanto no registrará las pulsaciones del teclado.

La solución más básica es, en el constructor de `Ventana`, hacer que `marco` sea quien registre dichas pulsaciones:

```
public  Ventana() {
  JFrame marco = new JFrame();
  marco.setVisible(true);
  setBackground(Color.black);
  marco.setSize(900,600);
  //addKeyListener(new Eventos());
  marco.addKeyListener(new Eventos());
  marco.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  marco.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  marco.add(this);
}
```

Otra solución, pero mucho menos descriptiva, es agregar un `grabFocus()` a ese contenedor.

```
public Ventana() {
  JFrame marco = new JFrame();
  marco.setVisible(true);
  setBackground(Color.black);
  marco.setSize(900,600);
  addKeyListener(new Eventos());
  marco.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  marco.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  marco.add(this);
  grabFocus();//Ahora el JPanel con sus listeners tendrá la prioridad en el JFrame
}
```